# Verbose reports need to be turned off for PCI compliance

Tags: iis-6, pci-compliance

We were informed from the PCI compliance team that we failed because "verbose reports" are on. I have never heard of this before. We have an IIS6 server. We are not running crystal reports or anything of the sort. I can't find any item in II6 called verbose reports. Does anyone know what verbose reports are and more importantly how to turn them off?

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for verbosity in IIS 6 is located at http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/d87ac473-eddb-4f7e-9a91-ce9f168b5635.mspx?mfr=true

They can be managed via a Provider file.  Documentation located at: http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/991e07c3-4143-48cc-ab39-8d49065a8388.mspx?mfr=true

Answer (score 0):

They are probably reffering to IIS (6) [Logggin Verbosity Levels](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/d87ac473-eddb-4f7e-9a91-ce9f168b5635.mspx?mfr=true)

Level 5 is **Verbose** :

> IIS providers report detailed information about requests

Answer (score 0):

The issue was a piece of software on the server called "Event Sentry" (not sure if that is spelled correctly). I haven't got the full details yet from the server guy and I will add more when I know more. However, I figured it was best to tell the issue in case anyone else has the issue.